# How often does GeoServer read its data Directory?

Tags: geoserver

Does GeoServer read its data folder only on startup or does it do so on every Get-request (for example when fetching data through WMS)? Is there some kind of a timer setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once at startup, unless you press the [config reload button](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/status.html) on the status page or POST or PUT the [rest reload page](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/reload.html).